# How do I execute options within loops - Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am new with Python and I am trying to get my code to run properly but I've been googling all day and cant find the fix. I am hoping someone can help me. 
I have my code (see below) and when I run it, It goes well until I select the option to add a transaction. Once I add my transaction amount, and choose any number (1-3) my loop then ends; which it shouldn't. It should take me to the desired option.

```
blockchain = []
def get_last_value():
    """extracting the last element of the blockchain list"""
    return(blockchain[-1])

def add_value(transaction_amount, last_transaction = [1]):
    blockchain.append([last_transaction, transaction_amount])

def get_transaction_value():
    user_value = float(input('Enter your transaction amount'))
    return user_value 

def get_user_choice():
    user_input = input("Please give your choice here:")
    return user_input

def print_block():
    for block in blockchain:
        print("Here is your block")
        print(block)

def verify_chain():
    index = 0
    valid = True
    for block in blockchain:
        if index == 0:
            index += 1
            continue
        elif block[0] == blockchain[index -1]:
            valid = True
        else:
            valid = False 
            break
        index += 1
    return valid 

tx_amount = get_transaction_value()
add_value(tx_amount)

while True:
    print("Choose an option")
    print('Choose 1 for adding a new transaction')
    print('Choose 2 for printing the blockchain')
    print('Choose 3 if you want to manipulate the data')
    print('Choose anything else if you want to quit')

# Once I choose an option, nothing happens. I need to know why

    user_choice = get_user_choice()

    if user_choice == 1:
        tx_amount = get_transaction_value()
        add_value(tx_amount, get_last_value())

    elif user_choice == 2:
        print_block()

    elif user_choice == 3:
        if len(blockchain) >= 1:
            blockchain[0] = 2

    else:
        break

    if not verify_chain():
        print('Blockchain manipulated')
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got an issue here. There is a typo in your spelling of valid in get_transaction_value().

```
if not verify_chain():

<ipython-input-2-358b629c0a68> in verify_chain()
     33             break
     34         index += 1
---> 35     return valid
     36 
     37 tx_amount = get_transaction_value()

NameError: name 'valid' is not defined
```

Comment: Thank you for that correction however, the code still does execute the commands. It does not get the transaction value nor am I able to manipulate the data. Any other suggestions. I used a debug and no errors.